# Android Firebase Query for Multiple values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch the all uid's of the doctor whose category is "abc"(example) and then store those retrieved uid's into an array list.
I want same results as displayed by the below sql query:
`select uid from doctors where category = "abc";`

[image: structure]

Code for next activity is written below

```
private void loadDoctors() {

    ArrayList<String> uid = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("doctor_list");

    for (int i =0;i<uid.size();i++){
        DatabaseReference doctors = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Doctors").child(uid.get(i));
        Adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DoctorModel, DoctorViewHolder>(
                DoctorModel.class,
                R.layout.doctors_home,
                DoctorViewHolder.class,
                doctors
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final DoctorViewHolder viewHolder, final DoctorModel model, int position) {
                viewHolder.doctor_name.setText(model.getName());

                Glide.with(Doctors.this).load(model.getProfileimage()).into(viewHolder.doctor_image);

                viewHolder.qualification.setText(model.getQualification());

                viewHolder.rating.setText(model.getRating());

            }

        };
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        doctors_list.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference doctorsRef = rootRef.child("Doctors");
Query categoryQuery = doctorsRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Cardiology");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> uidList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();
            uidList.add(uid);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
categoryQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

At the end, you'll have a list full of uids. One more thing to note, because Firebease API is asynchronous, you will be able to use that list only inside `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: got this error and the app crashed :- com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.kunal.onlineconsultation.Model.DoctorModel

Comment: actually i tried to put the list in intent extras and the next activity get crashed

Comment: A call to `.child(uid.get(i)` doesn't make any sense. Have you tried to use only the code I have provided you? Does the  `uidList` contains user IDs? Give a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: yes the list is getting retrieved but using the retrieved uid's i want to load the doctor details in next activity

Comment: Good to hear that you make it work. There isn't enough information to see why it is not working. However, what you are trying to achieve is a little bit complex so it can be answered in a simple comment. So I suggest you post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: cant you answer it here as i am not able to post question

Comment: As I said, you should add as a separate question. The second question is not related with initial one and cannot be answered in a comment.